# Understanding treatment of missing values in regression

Tags: regression, missing-data

I am reading the paper *[High-dimensional regression with noisy and missing data: Provable guarantees with non-convexity](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4454-high-dimensional-regression-with-noisy-and-missing-data-provable-guarantees-with-non-convexity.pdf)* by Loh and Wainwright, and I am interested in their approach to missing data.

Assuming a model $y = X \beta + \epsilon$, in example 2 at page 3, they suggest that if a data point in $X$ is missing with probability $\rho$, then you can create a new matrix $Z$ which is $X$ with the missing values replaced with $0$, and then an estimator of the covariance matrix $\Sigma_x$ can be written
$$
\frac{1}{n(1-\rho)^2} \left[ Z^TZ - \rho \ \text{diag}(Z^T Z) \right]
$$
(this is equation (8) in the paper). I am trying to understand this formula. It seems that it deflates the estimated variance of each covariate in $X$ in proportion to the probability of it having a missing value. What is the rationale for this? Is this a formalized technique that has a more in-depth treatment somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper seems to be proposing a different way of handling missing and noisy data. Personally, I would stick to more conventional methods of dealing with missing data than adopt a method yet to withstand time and scrutiny of many expert statistician. In what follows, I outline two conventional methods for dealing with missingness, one of which addresses issues with variance estimate.

Usually, missing data is treated as a separate step of model fitting/development. And the final stages of the analysis may be affected by how missing data was handled. Here are two examples:

1. You have very low number of cases with missing value and choose to impute using a "non-stochastic" approach such as nearest neighbor hot deck imputation. In this case regression analysis proceeds with the imputed data without need for variance adjustment
2. You have high number of cases with missingness (there is no rule for determining what is low or high missingness but I take any value >5% to be high) and proceed with a stochastic approach such as multiple imputation model. In this case, variance is adjusted using Rubin's rule for pooling variance across the corresponding coefficients from each multiply imputed dataset.

In essence, variance adjustment is conducted with multiply imputed datasets, but not through manipulation of the regression variance-covariance matrix.